# Quickly detect added/removed files inside git repository

Tags: git, bash, batch-file

Let's say I have a git repository with a .gitignore.

I want to 'snapshot' the repository at some point in time, and save some sort of digest in a location outside of the repository (I mustn't change the repository).

Then, I want to be able to detect if there are any files added or removed (but I don't care about changes) inside the git repository that aren't in the .gitignore since the last snapshot. I want this check to be very fast (it's for an editor plugin - response time is crucial).

If I only cared about committed files the solution would be trivial: store the HEAD commit hash in the snapshot, and compare commits. However I **do** care about uncommitted and untracked files - the only files I do not care about are the ones in `.gitignore`.

---

Basically I want to store the output of `git ls-files -c -o --exclude-standard` for some point in time, and see if it changed at a later point, without processing the entire output.

---

I would prefer pure git solutions, but otherwise I'd really like a cross-platform bash/batch solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following "[How to diff a file and output from the command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11733/7490)"

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/repo
d=$(git ls-files -c -o --exclude-standard | diff yourfile -)
if [[ "${d}" != "" ]]; then
  # there are diffs
fi
```

But that would still use the entire output of the `git ls-files` command though.